# Loop to remove card from player's hand not working

Tags: javascript, loops, object, if-statement, properties

I'm working on  a card game. It has a `playerHand` array which consists of 7 card objects with the properties `Value` `suit` and `cardName`. These are rendered on the screen as 7 divs with the shared class `.card` and unique classes that match the corresponding `cardName` e.g. `.six_hearts` `.ace_spades`

When a card div is clicked on, it receives the class `.selected`. The Div's `classList` is then pushed into an array entitled `SelectedCardsImg`.

What I'm trying to do is to remove the corresponding card object from the `playerHand` array and push it into a new array entitled `selectedCards`.

```
let selectedCardsImg = [];
let selectedCards = [];

    //loop through array of card images
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedCardsImg.length; i++) {

      //loop through playerHand array (card objects)
      for (var x = 0; x < playerHand.length; x++) {

        //if the current card image classlist contains the current card objects name
        if (selectedCardsImg[i].contains(playerHand[x].cardName)) {

          //push it into the new array selectedCards
          selectedCards.push(playerHand[x]);

          //remove it from the playerHand array
          playerHand.shift(playerHand[x]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Okay so I found a solution, instead of trying to do it all in one loop I wrote two loops. One that push's the card into the `selectedCards` array:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < playerHand.length; i++) {
        let currentCard = playerHand[i];
        let currentCardName = playerHand[i].cardName;

        for (var x = 0; x < selectedCardsImg.length; x++) {
        let result = selectedCardsImg[x].contains(currentCardName);

            if (result) {
    
                selectedCards.push(currentCard);
            } 
        }
    }
```

and then the second loop compares the `selectedCards` array to the `playerHand` array and removes the matches from `playerHand`:

```
      for (var i = 0; i < selectedCards.length; i++) {
    
       console.log(selectedCards[i]);

       for (var x = 0; x < playerHand.length; x++) {

            if (selectedCards[i] === playerHand[x]) {
                playerHand.splice(x, 1);
                console.log(playerHand);
                console.log(selectedCards)
            } 
       }

        
    }
```

Comment: What does selectedCardsImg contain? Strings?

Comment: `ImgArr` was supposed to be `selectedCardsImg` and returns a DOMTokenList of the 3 classes

Answer (score 0):

To get the removed card from playHand, you have to do like this:

`playerHand.shift()`

This will return the first element of the array.
Currently, you are passing an argument to `shift()` which is not correct.

You have to keep in mind that the length of `playerHand` will decrease by doing the `shift()` operation.

To modify the actual array, you can use `splice()` and remove the first element.

`playerHand.splice(index, 1)`

By this, your actual array will be modified and the length will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```js
let selectedCardsImg = [];
let selectedCards = [];

//loop through array of card images
for (var i = 0; i < selectedCardsImg.length; i++) {

    //loop through playerHand array (card objects)
    for (var x = 0; x < playerHand.length; x++) {

        //if the current card image classlist contains the current card objects name
        if (selectedCardsImg[i].contains(playerHand[x].cardName)) {

            //push it into the new array selectedCards
            selectedCards.push(playerHand[x]);

            //remove it from the playerHand array
            playerHand.splice(x,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method instead of .contains()

Also, [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) removes the first element from your array and returns that removed element. Since it changes the length of the array, if you count on the array "forward", you might skip items in the array.

Comment: Thanks for your input, i changed shift() to splice() because the card I'm trying to remove might not be the first item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible solution

```js
function action() {
    const playerHand = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    const selectedCardsImg = ['class1', 'class2', 'b'];
    const selectedCards = [];

    selectedCardsImg.forEach(card => {

        if (playerHand.some(hand => hand === card)) {
            
            selectedCards.push(card);
            playerHand.splice(playerHand.indexOf(card), 1)
        }
    });

    return {playerHand, selectedCardsImg, selectedCards}
}

console.log( action() );
```